Proof of Dirac delta representation as sum of exponentials
Physicists sometimes use the formula $\delta(x)=\frac1L\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} e^{2\pi i nx/L}$, where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta "function." I think the rigorous way to interpret this formula is as an identity of distributions, with $\delta(f):=f(0)$ and $$\left[\frac1L\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} e^{2\pi i nx/L}\right](f):= \frac1L\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \int_{-L/2}^{L/2} e^{2\pi i nx/L} f(x) \, dx.$$
So the formula claims
$$\frac1L\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \int_{-L/2}^{L/2} e^{2\pi i nx/L} f(x) \, dx = f(0)$$
for sufficiently nice $f : [-L/2, L/2] \to \mathbb C$. How can we prove this?

There is an analogous identity involving integration over $\mathbb R$ instead of summation over $\mathbb Z$, and I was able to prove that version of the formula by inserting a regulator $1 = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} e^{-\epsilon k^2}$, where $k$ is analogous to $n$ in the above case, and then performing suitable calculations. When I try to do this in the above case with regulators of the form $e^{-\epsilon n^2}$ or $e^{-\epsilon |n|}$, I get messy functions that I don't know what to do with.

You're essentially evaluating a Fourier series of $f$ at $0$

I think the $L$ in the physicists' formula serves as a sort of "regulator." The claim should be that the right-hand side of that equation approaches $\delta(x)$ as $L\to\infty$. (Convergence is meant in the sense of distributions.) [Physicists are allowed to assume that $L\to\infty$, that $\varepsilon\to0$, etc., without telling us nitpicky mathematicians.]

@AndreasBlass The $L$ here is not a regulator in the way that $\epsilon$ is. $L$ often represents the size of a finite "box," and sometimes physicists do take $L\to\infty$ eventually in order to let this box become all of space—but that limit isn't always taken, and regardless, the delta formula here is supposed to hold before taking the limit.

To convince yourself of this, you can take $L=1$, then evaluate the expression for $n\in{-N, ..., N}$ for large $N$ and your favorite $f$. Even taking $N=5$ works pretty well for $f = \operatorname{sech}^2.$

Isn't the identity actually $\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \delta(x-nL) = \frac1L\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} e^{2\pi i nx/L}$? That is, it produces a Dirac comb rather than just a single $\delta$.

@JohnBarber I think both formulas are right, depending on what function space $\mathcal S$ the distributions are supposed to be acting on. If $\mathcal S = \mathcal S(\mathbb R)$, your version is correct; if $\mathcal S = \mathcal S([-L/2, L/2])$, then my version is correct.

If we define the function $g(x)$ which is equal to $f(x)$ on $[-L/2,+L/2]$ and $0$ otherwise, then I believe the identity in your second expression can be proven simply by applying a form of the Poisson summation formula to $g(x)$.

We seek to prove the identity
\begin{equation}
\frac1L\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \int_{-L/2}^{L/2} e^{2\pi i nx/L} f(x) \, dx = f(0)\, , \qquad\qquad (1)
\end{equation}
where $f(x)$ is defined on $[-L/2, L/2]$. This can be done using a generalization of the Poisson summation formula.
Define the function
\begin{equation}
g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
f(x) & x\in [-L/2,L/2]\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Then the left hand side of Eq. (1) can be written as
\begin{equation}
\frac1L\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \int_{-L/2}^{L/2} e^{2\pi i nx/L} f(x) \, dx
=
\frac1L\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{2\pi i nx/L} g(x) \, dx
=
\frac1L\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}G(n/L)\, ,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
G(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2\pi i \xi x} g(x) \, dx \qquad\qquad (2)
\end{equation}
is the Fourier transform of $g(x)$. (Note: Eqs. (1) and (2) have different signs in the exponent. This doesn't matter, however, since $n$ ranges over all of $\mathbb Z$, so we can always make the substitution $n\rightarrow -n$.)
One form of the Poisson summation formula, given here, states that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\frac1P S(n/P) e^{2\pi inx/P}
=
\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}s(x + nP)\, ,\qquad\qquad(3)
\end{equation}
where $S$ is the Fourier transform of $s$. Now, take $x=0$, $P = L$, $S = G$, and $s = g$ in Eq. (3), and we are left with
\begin{equation}
\frac1L \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}G(n/L)
=
\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}g(nL)
=
f(0)
\end{equation}
And we're done.

One needs some smoothness assumptions to evaluate the Fourier series at a point. Some equalities hold as L2 functions, and eveluation at a point is not a defined operation in L2.
